# Send command to instrument by joining file path string with command string

Tags: python, string, instruments, pyvisa

Generally, I am able to successfully send command to my Tektroniks oscilloscope using this:

```
handle_Instrument.write("RECALL:SETUP 'C:/Setup1.set' ")
```

However, if I were to assign the file path (`C:/Setup1.set`) as a separate string and then join it with the command (`RECALL:SETUP`), the instrument does not respond. Here is the code I tried:

```
filename = str("Setup1.set")
filepath = str("C:/") + str(filename)
completeCommand = str("RECALL:SETUP ")+str(filepath)
handle_Instrument.write(completeCommand)
```

I also tried to add `"` around the command but no help. Any suggestions?

```
handle_Instrument.write(str("\"") + completeCommand + str("\""))
```

Comment: have you tried to join file path using os.path.join()?

Comment: In your first example you surrounded the file path within the command with quotes, in the second example you don't.

Comment: In `str("Setup.set")`, `str()` is pointless, `"Setup.set"` is already a string. (In fact this is the same for all your uses of `str`.)

Comment: To figure out problems like this on your own, you can add `print()` statements to see if the values of variables are what you expect. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more debugging tips.

Answer (score 1):

Added single quote"'" to enclose file path to resolve the issue